# How to configure DbContext of EntityFrameworkCore when using NInject

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

In the ConfigureServices of .net core startup class you can configure dbcontext as follows.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DotNetCoreT1DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

How do I configure this, if I use NInject or may be Autofac?

With NInject, I tried the following.

```
kernel.Bind<DotNetCoreT1DbContext>().ToMethod(m => new DotNetCoreT1DbContext(GetDbContextOptionsForCurrentRequest()));
```

with GetDbContextOptionsForCurrentRequest defined as follows.

```
private DbContextOptions GetDbContextOptionsForCurrentRequest()
{
   var options = new DbContextOptions();
   return options;
}
```

The problem is I cannot newup DbContextOptions and so the above does not work. Its not a public ctor.

How do I go about using NInject or Autofac and configure EF Core DbContext?

Comment: Ninject does not have any direct ASP.NET Core integration, so you will need to roll it yourself. As for Autofac, there’s an [official integration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) which allows you to replace the built-in dependency injection container, providing full compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is I cannot newup DbContextOptions and so the above does not work. Its not a public ctor.

Build up the options using the options builder. That is what it is for as `DbContextOptions` is not designed to be directly constructed in your application code.

For example

```
private DbContextOptions GetDbContextOptionsForCurrentRequest() {
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DotNetCoreT1DbContext>();

    //configure builder
    //optionsBuilder.Use*(...);

    //get options
    var options = optionsBuilder.Options;

    return options;
}
```

Reference [Configuring DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions)